# Where did the word Todash Space came from?

Tags: stephen-king

Was Todash named after a fictional person who came up with the term "Todash Space"?

Comment: Good question. I can't find anything on google to suggest the origin other than this essay; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PM0tBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=stephen+king+todash&source=bl&ots=0oBP29KKzL&sig=ZNTKIovM3HSvtQiWwFppGfHUtAo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V2RaVcWgLMiI7Aa-34HYCQ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwDTgK#v=onepage&q=stephen%20king%20todash&f=false

Comment: Who has voted this "unclear what you're asking" and why? It seems very clear to *me*.

Comment: @Richard -[In Ref to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_works_related_to_The_Dark_Tower_series) "Todash Darkness" in King's work on *The Mist* and connected to *The Dark Tower*. It says in the Wiki article: *In the novella "The Mist", the cause of the Mist is alluded to be a tear between universes, similar to the Todash Darkness, a concept explored in the series, both of which supposedly renders its inhabitants "blind" and contains horrible creatures which prey on them. Additionally, several creatures described are physically similar to some of those shown in the series.*

Comment: Also, from the [Dark Tower Wiki Page](http://darktower.wikia.com/wiki/Todash_Space). Is this term something which Stephen King came up with to describe his books, or a term which is used to describe some of King's works? I guess that's the real question.

Comment: Well I translated the tá dáth into Irish and came back as "color"

Comment: King often deliberately mangles original words into their perceived sounds -  I've always thought of it as Tau dash, or T- space, which works out to spacetime  where proper time has been subtracted out -  every possible thing happens always forever - go there and go mad - just hadda make this note cause I just ate "Stranger Things" and if that ain't "The Shop" I'll eat my shoe  :-)

Comment: @Möoz This question could be improved by adding, in which book(s) and context the term is used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he took inspiration (as he mentions) from the poem 'Childe Roland to the Dark tower Came'. In this particular case, I suspect he mashed a couple of words together from a portion of the poem upon which he was drawing the very inspiration that would foment into 'Todash'

> XXII.
>   Glad was I when I reached the other bank. 
>   Now for a better country. Vain presage! 
>   Who were the strugglers, what war did they wage, 
>   Whose savage trample thus could pad the dank 
>   soil to a pl**ash**? **Toad**s in a poisoned tank 
>   Or wild cats in a red-hot iron cage -

Comment: This seems like a reach